# Insert shortcode into editor after clicking button

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I've created a button next to Add Media button. When the button is clicked, I want it to automatically insert shortcode into editor like this:

```
[myshortcode]
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example and you can tweak as you like:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function addshortcode() {
    var shortcode = "[myshortcode]";
    document.myform.editor.value += shortcode;
}
</script>

<form name="myform">
<input type="button" value="Add Shortcode" onClick="addshortcode();"><br />
<textarea name="editor"></textarea>
</form>
```